# Sudden icons and color changed and I cannot revert it

Tags: icons, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

Icons have changed, terminal is now white. I cannot recall doing something that might have done this and I don't know how to bring my old setup back. This one looks horrible

[image]

[image]

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have turned on "High contrast" in "Universal Access. Find the setting in the "Settings" app and turn it off again.

Comment: This is it. Universal access was actually off. Some icons were back after reboot, but when I put this on and off again, it came back to normal. Thanks